# CSS: page-break-before, always, except the first time?

Tags: html, css, page-break

I'm trying to create a pretty-print html page. I need to force a page-break, between top-level constructs, so I added a CSS class to the top-level element of each construct, and set page-break-before:always in the CSS for that class. E.g.:

```
<body>
<div class="prettyprint">
    <div class='toplevel'>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class='toplevel'>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
</body>

.prettyprint .toplevel { page-break-before:always; }
```

My problem is I get a blank page, before the first top-level element.  Which makes perfect sense, considering what page-break-before:always is supposed to do.  But I don't want it.

So, one option is to not include the "toplevel" class in the first element, or to provide a new "firsttoplevel" class that doesn't set page-break-before:always, and set it for the first top-level element, and then use "toplevel" for all the others.  I could do it, easily enough, but it seems like it's violating separation of concerns.

So I was wondering if there was a way to do this in CSS?  To set a rule that would apply only to the first "toplevel" child of "prettyprint"?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:first-child
```

might work but pretty sure there are issues with IE6, see: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html

edit: doesn't work in IE6, and for newer versions of IE doctype must be used for it to work.

Comment: +1 the best way I can think of. You could use jQuery to add the functionality for IE6.

Comment: IE breaks some prints even in current version [did for me at least], I wouldn't care much about IE6  :P

Answer (score 9):

See a good description on page breaks at: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/

The following works well on Chrome v56.  Create a rule that implements `page-break-before:always` but suppress that rule when it is applied to the first of it's type.

```css
.print-per-page {
  page-break-before: always;
}

.print-per-page:first-of-type {
  page-break-before: avoid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="print-per-page">Page 1</div>
  <div class="print-per-page">Page 2</div>
  <div class="print-per-page">Page 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `:first-of-type` worked in wkhtmltopdf when `:first-child` did not. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
        .prettyprint {
            page-break-before: always;
            margin-top:0;
        }

        .prettyprint :first-of-type {
            page-break-before: avoid;
        }
```

Comment: an explanation would be beneficial